# TemplateSyntaxError at /messages/inbox/ 'account_tags' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:

Tags: django, pinax

I am using pinax_messages and pinax_templates.

I am not able to go to the page : http://127.0.0.1:8000/messages/inbox/

I am getting a strange error and dont understand the problem.

I am getting the error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /messages/inbox/
'account_tags' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
admin_list
admin_modify
admin_urls
bootstrap
cache
crispy_forms_field
crispy_forms_filters
crispy_forms_tags
crispy_forms_utils
i18n
l10n
log
pinax_messages_tags
static
tz
```

I am not able to find any help on google.

```
{% load i18n %}
{% load account_tags %}


<ul class="account-bar">
    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
        <li class="user">
            <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
            {% user_display request.user %}
        </li>
        <li class="settings">
            <a href="{% url 'account_settings' %}">
                <i class="fas fa-cog"></i>
                {% trans "Settings" %}
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="logout">
            <a id="account_logout" href="{% url 'account_logout' %}">
                <i class="fas fa-power-off"></i>
                {% trans "Log out" %}
            </a>
        </li>
    {% else %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'account_login' %}">{% trans "Log in" %}</a></li>
        {% if ACCOUNT_OPEN_SIGNUP %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'account_signup' %}">{% trans "Sign up" %}</a></li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
</ul>

<form id="accountLogOutForm" style="display: none;" action="{% url 'account_logout' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
</form>
```

Comment: You are trying to load `account_tags` in your template, like  `{% load account_tags %} `. But this **tag library is not  registered**.

Comment: How am I supposed to rectify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using django-user-accounts , so i think you dont have django-user-accounts installed with pip , or you might have forgot register it to the settings file

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # ...
    "account",
    # ...
)
```

and also the template context processor

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = [
    ...
    "account.context_processors.account",
    ...
]
```

and also middleware

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    ...
    "account.middleware.LocaleMiddleware",
    "account.middleware.TimezoneMiddleware",
    ...
]
```

Comment: I have tried this solution. I get the following message no such table account_account. It doesnt work

Comment: you should sync the database with migrate command

Comment: I now get the following error : OperationalError at /messages/inbox/
no such table: account_account

Comment: I have now 2 accounts urls ....path(r"^accounts/", include("django.contrib.auth.urls")), and  url(r"^account/", include("account.urls")),  why do I have 2 account urls? what is the right one to keep?

Comment: Eureka! This one step was the problem. Brilliant work buddy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to load `account_tags` in your template, like `{% load account_tags %}` . But this **tag library is not registered**.

You have to add **app** of `account_tags`  in   `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Or add it to **libraries** in your `settings.py`:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {   
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            ...
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                ...
            ],
            'libraries': {
                'account_tags': 'myapp.templatetags.account_tags',
            },
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'myapp.templatetags.account_tags': No module named 'myapp'

Comment: @sly_Chandan, **my_aap** is as exapmle. Where is exact location of your file account_tags.py?

Comment: Lib\site-packages\pinax\templates\templates\

Comment: @sly_Chandan, have you tried to remove `{% load account_tags %}`?

Comment: yes the code breaks because of line {% user_display request.user %}

Comment: @sly_Chandan, Have you added `pinax.templates` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231660/discussion-between-sly-chandan-and-nksm).